# Estimating real world translation between two cameras through feature matching

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, pose-estimation

I have two calibrated cameras looking at an overlapping scene. I am trying to estimate the pose of camera2 with respect to camera1 (because camera2 can be moving; but both camera1 and 2 will always have some features that are overlapping).

I am identifying features using SIFT, computing the fundamental matrix and eventually the essential matrix. Once I solve for R and t (one of the four possible solutions), I obtain the translation up-to-scale, but is it possible to somehow compute the translation in real world units? There are no objects of known size in the scene; but I do have the calibration data for both the cameras. I've gone through some info about Structure from Motion and stereo pose estimation, but the concept of scale and the correlation with real world translation is confusing me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the classical scale problem with structure from motion.

The short answer is that you must have some other source of information in order to resolve scale.

This information can be about points in the scene (e.g. terrain map), or some sensor reading from the moving camera (IMU, GPS, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually do have a GPS and an IMU providing information from the moving camera, but the pose coming from those is noisy to some extent : so the idea was to enhance the accuracy of those by using feature matching. I might have a good position estimate from the GPS at frame 1, which might drift in the subsequent frames. Is there a way I can use a "guess" of the distance to obtain a much more accurate value?

Comment: The standard approach to solve this is using Bundle Adjustment.   This will give you the relative translation and rotation of the cameras with relation to the first camera.  You can use the GPS information to resolve the scale and fix the translations.